# Best way in SQL to self-join three field table so that keys without values get assigned key and particular count

Tags: sql

Say we have a table:

| key | value | _count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 3 |
| c | d | 2 |

that we want to expand such that each key gets mapped to each distinct value in the table and gets a `_count` of 0 if the key-value pair did not already have a count. For example, for the table above, I would like to see:

| key | value | _count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 3 |
| a | d | 0 |
| c | d | 2 |
| c | b | 0 |

I have a working solution:

```
WITH key_value_pairs AS (
  SELECT 
    a.key, 
    b.value
  FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT key FROM table) a, (SELECT DISTINCT value FROM table) b
  )

SELECT 
  kvp.key, 
  kvp.value, 
  COALESCE(base._count, 0) _count 
FROM 
  key_value_pairs kvp
LEFT JOIN 
  table base ON base.key = kvp.key AND base.value = kvp.value;
```

But I suspect there may be an easier/more readable/more efficient way to implement this -- any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `cross join` with `left join` for a shorter solution:

```
select t1.key, t2.value, coalesce(t3._count, 0) from tbl t1 
cross join tbl t2 left join tbl t3 on t1.key = t3.key and t2.value = t3.value;
```